# What causes "Unable to add module" error for Thunderbird security device?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm attempting to add support for the US Dept. of Defense's "Common Access Card" to Thunderbird using the PKCS #11 provider called CACKey (v. 0.6.5). This is on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid).

I built the provider and added it to Firefox (v. 13.0) with absolutely no trouble. It works great.

However, when I try to add the module to Thunderbird (v. 13.0) using essentially the same steps, it fails with a message, "Unable to add module". No further details are provided.

I then tried creating a brand new Thunderbird profile, in case there was something in my old settings that was causing a problem. This didn't make a difference, though.

What might cause this problem?

Are there additional logging options for Thunderbird that might give more useful information about what is happening?

Comment: Have you already checked the error console? (Tools->Error Console)?

Comment: @GurkenPapst Yes, but nothing is logged when I attempt to add the module.